# Dropdownlist based on database and to merge column when they have same ID

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have the examples of data saved in the database as shown in the figure:
[list of attachments uploaded by 3 different users (STAFF_145, STAFF_143 and STAFF_147)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoMgo.jpg)

When I called it from gridview list, it shows like this:
[Gridview of list attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30HZN.jpg)

Based on the gridview, I tried to apply the "Attachments & TRF" column with `<asp:Label ID="txt_training_attach_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("training_attach_name") %>' ReadOnly="true">`.

It shows error when I've change to "Dropdownlist" instead of using "Label" or "Textbox".

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: ''txt_training_attach_name' has a
> SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list
> of items. Parameter name: value'

The error points out at here when I used Dropdownlist:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     Grid_Attachment.DataSource = dt;
     Grid_Attachment.DataBind();
}
```

It is possible if I want to make a gridview as shown as like this?
[Dropdownlist and Merge Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRWtD.jpg)

I've try many ways since last month but I still cannot get the answer. Appreciate if you could help me. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You need to group the results up so the staff id is unique, and provide a datasource for each dropdown that is the total list of items with that same staff id

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if the staff table of up-loaded files is a different table then the one that supposed to drive the grid.

if it is for some reason, then build a group by query that does not include the file(s) column, and group by so you wind up with a SINGLE row for each staff member.

So, then we can drop in a grid list this:

And I am going to use a listbox in place of a combo (dropdown), so it will NICE display the files - you can change that to a dropdown if you want - same code

So, the markup might be this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Firstname" HeaderText="First Name"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name"    />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TrainingDate" HeaderText="Training Date"       DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ApplicationDate" HeaderText="Application Date" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProgramTitle" HeaderText="Program Title"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TrainingCost" HeaderText="Training Cost"  DataFormatString="{0:c}" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Documents Submitted">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ListBox ID="cboFiles" runat="server" Width="200PX"
                            DataTextField ="FileName"
                            DataValueField="FileName">                
                        </asp:ListBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Note how we added a listbox (as noted, use a drop down if you want).

So, the code to fill this gv would thus be this:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * from Users ORDER BY FirstName");
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }


    DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }

        return rstData;
    }
```

However, for each row, we need to load up the list of files for that one row. As noted, I don't know if you have two tables here - or one. (but, it really does not matter - as noted, use a group-by for this main grid data source.

Now, the only extra part is to use the gv "row data bound" event. This fires for each row during render, and is the idea event to load up the combo or list box.

That code is thus this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // get PK row id (user id)
            int? PKID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["ID"] as int?;
            string strSQL = "SELECT FileName FROM MyFiles WHERE User_ID = " + PKID;
            DataTable rstFiles = MyRst(strSQL);
           ListBox cboFiles = e.Row.FindControl("cboFiles") as ListBox;

            cboFiles.DataSource = rstFiles;
            cboFiles.DataBind();
            cboFiles.Rows = 1;
            if (rstFiles.Rows.Count > 1)
                cboFiles.Rows = rstFiles.Rows.Count;
        }
    }
```

And above I do have two columns. One is JUST file name, and one column is the full path name + file to the up-load folder. If you don't have just a file name column, then we can write a bit of code to JUST include + show file name.

the results of running the above is thus this:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU for your response. Really appreciate. I'll try to go through this and will be back to you soon. To be informed that I did the gridview from a different table (I used INNER JOIN)